# How to pass parameters to timeit function in python?

Tags: python, timeit

```
import timeit
#those are the parameters that need to be passed
list1=["Ahmed","Ahmedd"]
#loop through the parameters
for x in list1:
mysetup=x
#the function to be tested 
mycode='''
#testing if the string is unique
def is_unique_chars_using_set(string):
#Solution Using Set
characters_seen = set()
for char in string:
    if char in characters_seen:
        return False
    characters_seen.add(char)
return True'''
print (timeit.timeit(stmt = mycode,number = 1000000))
```

How to pass those parameters to `timeit`?

Comment: `mycode` never _calls_ the function. If it did, e.g. with `is_unique_chars_using_set(x)`, then you could do `setup=f"x={x!r}"`.

Answer (score 0):

The code here doesn't uses the list actually. The timeit cannot look inside the loop. (ie. It should be in proper range)

The code below will work for you

```
import timeit
#those are the parameters that need to be passed
list1=["Ahmed","Ahmedd"]
#loop through the parameters

#the function to be tested 
mycode='''
#testing if the string is unique
def is_unique_chars_using_set(string):
    #Solution Using Set
    characters_seen = set()
    for char in string:
        if char in characters_seen:
            return False
        characters_seen.add(char)
    return True'''
print (timeit.timeit(stmt = mycode,number = 1000000))
```

**If the for loop is needed, Then you need to include the for loop inside the "my code"**

```
import timeit
mycode='''
list1=["Ahmed","Ahmedd"]
for x in list1:
    mysetup=x
    #testing if the string is unique
    def is_unique_chars_using_set(string):
        #Solution Using Set
        characters_seen = set()
        for char in string:
            if char in characters_seen:
                return False
            characters_seen.add(char)
        return True'''
print (timeit.timeit(stmt = mycode,number = 1000000))
```

Comment: all I want to pass multiple parameters to the is_unique function while testing each case how much time it will take?